Trying to understand coordinate transformations
So, I don't really understand why $\mathrm{d}x$ or generally any differential is equal to the sum of this differential over each one of the corresponding spherical coordinates times each spherical coordinate. Where is the following derived from?
$$\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\mathrm{d}r + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\mathrm{d}\phi$$
or in general,
$$\mathrm{d}x_\nu = \sum_{\sigma=1}^3\frac{\partial x_\nu}{\partial x'_\sigma}\mathrm{d}x'_\sigma$$

Your misunderstanding is WAY WAY WAY more basic than general relativity. You need to start by learning calculus first. You are not ready for GR in any way. PS - I am not demeaning you in any way. I am merely pointing out that if you are having trouble with this sort of stuff, you will simply not follow anything in GR.

This question isn't really about general relativity per se.

To understand $$\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\mathrm{d}r + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\mathrm{d}\phi$$ take a curve $t\mapsto (r(t),\theta(t),\phi(t))$ and apply the chain rule to $x(r(t),\theta(t),\phi(t)),.$ Your second formula looks strange. You don't transform from  $x$ to $x,.$

Can you tell me all the mathematical background I need to have in order to understand GR?(and perhaps recommend any books) Thank you very much

It looks like you are trying to state the chain rule, one of the fundamental laws of calculus, which relates total $d$ and partial $\partial$ derivatives. For a function $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}dx_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}dx_2+...+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}dx_n$$
This can be understood heuristically as follows: let us say that $f(x,y)$
is the height $f$ of a surface at any coordinate point $(x,y)$.  As an example, let us try to find the change in vertical height $f$ between two points on this oddly sloped table.

It is sloped in both the $x$ and $y$ directions shown, and those slopes are different, but they are constant in each direction.

Going from points $f_0$ to $f_1$, if we travel first a distance $dy$, the change in height over that distance is $f_y~dy$, where $f_y$ is the slope in the $y$ direction.  We then move a distance $dx$ in the $x$ direction, with our height changing by a further  $f_x~dx$, where $f_x$ is the slope in the $x$ direction.  (Note, red dotted lines are lines of constant height, parallel to the floor).
The total height change from $f_0$ to $f_1$ is the sum of the solid red lines:
$$df=f_x~dx + f_y~dy$$
And the slopes $f_x$ and $f_y$ are nothing but the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.
Therefore:
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$
which is the chain rule.  This can be extended to any number of independent (i.e. orthogonal) variables.
Because we are considering small (infinitesimal) changes, a surface or function of arbitrary overall shape will take the form of a plane like the table shown, with a constant linear slope in the direction of each variable – in the same way that in $\rm 1D$ calculus, any smooth curve becomes a straight line if you zoom in to an infinitesimal distance.  So this analysis applies to any smooth surface or function (i.e. with no holes or other exotic features).

SIDE NOTE: In general relativity or curved spaces in general (per the original question), the chain rule and the product rule are the same, but when differentiating vectors you have to account for both the vector magnitude and the unit vector itself changing with location, i.e.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\vec{\bf v}~=~\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(v_j\bf{\vec{e}_j}\right)~=~\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}\boldsymbol{\vec{e}_j}+v_j\frac{\partial  \boldsymbol{\vec{e}_j}}{\partial x_i}$$
